# Cannot launch IIS Express for just created project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I haven't had this problem before.

I have created a blank solution in Visual Studio 2019 and then, I created an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).

I did nothing else, just run the application.

After rebuilt, this error was shown:

> Unable To Launch IIS Web server. Failed to register URL
>   "https://localhost:44374/" for site "MyProject " application "/".
>   Error description: Cannot create a file when that file already exists
>   (0x800700b7)

I have searched for a possible solution but I did not find someone with the same problem.

How can I solve it?

EDIT:

When I launch IIS Express by command line, the same error exists, but only for https URL of the site:

[image]

Comment: You might run IIS Express from command line to rule out Visual Studio interference, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Comment: @LexLi Hello... the same happened, but in this case, the error shows that the problem occurs for the https version of the site. I have updated the question.

Comment: For that I will doubt if the antivirus on this machine is the culprit.

Comment: @LexLix I have other site that works so Antivirus is not the case here. Furthermore, I have removed https binding and then launch iisexpress from command line and it works. But when trying to debug the program, VS2019 insists in launching IISEXPRESS and now it is showing the same error, but with the http site.

Comment: @LexLi I hace used other port and create bindings by IP and localhost. When launching the application from VS2019 the same error occurs. When launching IISExpress from command line, it starts correctly, but when running VS2019 project, it says that the port is already in use.